# Prevent variable from being assigned twice

Tags: java

I have a question, I am creating a class, and in my class, i have some variables that i want just to be assigned once, but i would like multiple instances of the class. Example:

```
public class UserHandler{

private ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addUser(String user) {
users.add(user)
}

}
```

This is just some example code. Would the ArrayList be instantiated multiple times, or just once, if i create multiple instances of the class?

Comment: If you want a single ArrayList shared by all instances, make it static.

Comment: Make use of static variables.

Comment: ArrayList will instantiate multiple times in above code. If you want to share ArrayList object by all your instances then make it static

Comment: make it static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is declared as

```
private ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
```

it will be created once for each instance of UserHandler.

If you change the declaration to **`static`**

```
private static ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
```

it will be created only once and shared between different instances.

---

You can find more about class members (`static` keyword) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on the tutorial of Oracle:

> `static` keyword to create fields and methods that **belong to the class**, **rather than to an instance** of the class.

Comment: If he makes that static variable private then he can not access it from other classes.

Comment: @Abhijeet Who said that it must be accessed from other classes?

Comment: Well If he want to create multiple object of that class. Then he might need static object to be accessible in those classes where he is going to instantiate.

Comment: he can use `getter setter` for other class

Comment: @Abhijeet is also possible to add a method to get a single user knowing its index. A method to add a user already exists. Hiding information is generally a good practice, so for example is it possible to change the ArrayList to a standard array without changing other classes.